# how to have color-bar in spectrogram in angular

Tags: angular, d3.js, colormap, spectrogram, wavesurfer.js

I have made a spectrogram of an audio file using wavesurfer with spectrogram plugin and colormap in angular. I want to add colorbar to it. Please suggest how to implement that.

```
this.wave = WaveSurfer.create({
        container: '#waveform',
        waveColor: '#5A5A5A',//'violet',
        progressColor: '#C2B280',//'purple',
        height:200,
        barHeight: 2,
        plugins: [
          SpectrogramPlugin.create({
            container: '#wave-spectrogram',
            labels:true,
            colorMap:colors
          }),
       ]})
```

[image: expected]
[image: current]